# Is Netbeans a good IDE for C/C++ nowadays?

Tags: ide, netbeans

I searching for and IDE that gives me a (mostly) uniform experience on Linux/Windows and C/C++ and Java. I'm somewhat comfortable with using Netbeans on Windows and I'd like to know what to expect of it on C. I heard the Visual Studio debugger is quite good on C, does this extend to Mono? Is it really more powerful than the one on Netbeans?

Comment: Yeah, I searched. The past topics don't address my questions. Specifically about C/C++. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been using NetBeans for C++ development on Linux for the last month or two and love it.  I'm working on an large code base 1+million lines of code.  As long as your project references appropriately, I've found that NetBeans will provide "intellisense" information with hardly any issues.  Now, it's not perfect, and is definitely not as good as Java, but I've not found a better alternative.  NetBeans debugger, which is a front-end to gdb, works well also.  Much easier, and in my experience more stable than DDD.  I've not tried Mono projects using NetBeans so I can't speak to that.

This link explains how to setup a C++ project in NetBeans and may shed more light on the subject for you.  This is for NetBeans 6.7 [NetBeans C/C++](http://www.netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is quite usable as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use codeblocks it is also a well and exceptionally good for c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, since it consumes extreme amounts of memory and can hog your CPU completely if you have a lot of projects open. It actually uses every bit of CPU it can if it feels for it, and it does so for a **long** time, rendering the whole application useless. This is of course completely unacceptable for a modern UI application. It also feels kind of sluggish.

Because of this I switched to [Visual Studio Code for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). It's not a full blown IDE but I don't need that anyways. I'm not in the "flow" of it yet, but I think it has potential.

Answer (score -1):

The problem of VS C++ is don't have intellisense. Netbeans C++ is a good product. But i suggest DevC++ editor, its free and come with lot of pluggins and intellisense.

Comment: DevC++ is buggy and no longer under active development.

Comment: DevC++ is dead. Code::Blocks is the new DevC++

Comment: "The problem of VS C++ is don't have intellisense".  You're saying visual studio doesn't have intellisense?  that's simply not true *shakes head*

Comment: I don't know other releases but in VC++ 2012 intellisense not exists for unmanaged code. I need instal VS2010 to get this.